# Crystalline long range order

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, crystals

I am reading [an article](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys1220), in which the phrase "crystalline long-range order" appears. I am not really sure what this phrase means here. I tried to find references online, but there seems to be little discussion of it. Does it refer to that, for example, the crystal has some periodicity along some direction in real space?

Comment: The article is behind a paywall. Can you post the relevant part of the article in your question?

Comment: Crystals, by definition, have long range order. Without more context, what the authors mean is hard to decipher.

Comment: After looking through the paper, which is about 1D topological insulators with dislocations, the point is how can one treat the defects appropriately. So, they emphasize starting with an assumption of long-range order and add defects, and then show that one does not have to assume long-range order to begin with. So the pairing of long-range and crystalline is just to emphasize that approach.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks! When you say "Crystals, by definition, have long-range order," what exactly are you referring to by "long-range order"?

Comment: In an ideal crystal, the position of every atom is fixed in an infinitely repeating pattern by the Bravais lattice and basis.

Comment: @JonCuster, Thanks! I think this answers my question here. And, I believe that this is what the authors meant in their paper!

Comment: @JohnRennie, thanks for your comment. But, it's hard to explain it in a few words because the idea, as Jon Custer mentioned, is kinda scattered throughout the paper.